# How to add element for QML ListModel using Javascript?

Tags: qt, qml

I have created one nested ListModel.

```
ListModel {
    id: mainModel
    ListElement {
        mainName: "Alphabet"

        subAlpha: [
            ListElement { alphaName: "A" },
            ListElement { alphaName: "B" }
        ]
    } }
```

How can I add element in inner list using javascript? In other words, how can I add element to subAlpha model?

Comment: @clearkimura Programming questions related to the Ubuntu SDK (which uses QML) are on-topic.

Comment: @muru I hardly noticed the `qml` tag, which was the only clue in the question earlier. So, I have edited the question using "QML" keyword to make it clearly on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`subAlpha.append()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#append-method).  This method takes a Javascript object as an argument, which it uses to create a new ListElement with those keys and values.

A working example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

ListView {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    ListModel {
        id: mainModel
        ListElement {
            name: "Alphabet"
            subAlpha: [
                ListElement {
                    alphaName: "A"
                },
                ListElement {
                    alphaName: "B"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    model: mainModel
    delegate: Column {
        Text { text: name }
        Row {
            Repeater {
                model: subAlpha
                Text { text: alphaName }
            }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        mainModel.get(0).subAlpha.append({alphaName: "C"})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it valid JSON/Javascript

```
a = {
  id: mainModel,
  ListElement: {
    mainName: "Alphabet",

    subAlpha: [
       { alphaName: "A" },
       { alphaName: "B" }
    ]
  } 
}
```

and then add to subAlpha

```
a.ListElement.subAlpha.push({ alphaName: "C" })
```

Comment: The question is about QML, not Javascript.  Though QML does use Javascript for its procedural parts, its declarative language is not Javascript.  The OP's code is perfectly valid QML; changing it to Javascript vastly changes its meaning.

Comment: thx @robert-schroll, I did't see that. My bad :(